# Why unclosed file size is 4 bytes

Tags: c++

Why this code creates file with size 4 bytes, though file unclosed.

```
ofstream output("number.bin");
int16_t value = 2570;
output.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), sizeof(value));
```

Comment: How do you check the size? And *when* do you check the size? What happens inside your program between the three lines you show, and when you check the size? And please try to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: open as binary `ofstream output("number.bin", std::ios::binary);`. And close the file before checking the size .

Comment: Think about buffering. What is it? What does it do?

Comment: I don't quite grok the relevance of whether the file is closed or not. Are you asking how buffering works? Are you asking what bytes are written to the file by this code? Be more clear.

Comment: @Peter: `sizeof(int16_t)` is commonly '2', not '4'.  Although the question doesn't spell it out, this is likely the primary source of curiosity for the OP.  _That plus the automatic scope-based `close` that C++ applies._

Comment: @AlexandrLavrov: Something that you may not be aware of is that the `ofstream` will automatically close the file when `output` goes out of scope ([`close` is "is not usually invoked directly"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/close)).  Therefore, it is unlikely that the file is actually unclosed when you check its size.  To make your question more clear, it would be helpful if you would follow up with edits that address the notes in the comments.

Comment: ...It's also curious that you've chosen to write the _special_ value `2570` (0x0A0A). Maybe you could comment on how that particular value was chosen -- and whether or not you've tried with other values.

Answer (score 6):

It's easier to understand if you know hexadecimal notation and about [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding.

The hexadecimal representation of decimal `2570` is `0x0a0a`. The byte `0x0a` is the ASCII value for newline `\n`.

Since you open the file in *text* mode, the system might translate single newlines into the platform-dependent newline sequence. On Windows newline in text-files are the carriage-return/newline combination `\r\n`.

So when you write the value `0x0a0a` it's like you're writing two newlines which will each be translated into two bytes, for a total length of four bytes (`\r\n\r\n`).

To solve your problem you should open the file in *binary* mode, where all data written to the file will be written *as-is* without any translations.

```
ofstream output("number.bin", std::ios::binary);
```

---

On old Mac systems, OS9 and earlier, then newline was represented as carriage-return `\r`. So on such a system the amount of bytes written would be correct but the data inside the file would seem incorrect (in the file it would be `0x0d0d`).

Answer (score 4):

You opened the file as a text file, probably on Windows. The number 2570 in hex is 0x0a0a, i.e. two 0x0a bytes, which corresponds to two newlines. When writing text files in windows, each newline is represented by two bytes `\r\n`, so you write four bytes instead of two.

Open the file as binary to fix this:

```
ofstream output("number.bin", std::ios::binary);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why unclosed file size is 4 bytes

### This behavior is *implementation specific*.

From what I understand of the C++11 standard (see [n3337](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n3337.pdf)), you cannot reliably predict the behavior.

It depends upon your [operating system](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (could be different on Linux and on Windows), your [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) (could be different on [ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), on [VFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT), and on [ZFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS)), your [standard C++ library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) implementation (could be different with [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) standard library and [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) one), etc....

So several layers of code are involved. Each is adding implementation details.
At last, IO is generally buffered. You may want to use [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush)

Comment: This question from job interview. The exact question was “Which will be the output file size?” 
After the interview I run this code and see the result.
As far as I understand this number converts(casts to char*) to two symbols of new line each of which is of size two bytes. Though we pass to write the size 2 bytes(sizeof int16)